# How to make child control handle accelerator command of parent CView

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a CFormView, and a child CListCtrl control. I can handle 
accelerator events, like Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V ... in CFormView without 
problem, by defining below message handler:

```
    ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_COPY, &CMyFormView::OnEditCopy)
```

Now I want my CListCtrl handle these commands differently. I want to 
implement OnEditCopy in CListCtrl class, rather than implement logic 
in the view class. How can I pass the accelerator events from CView to 
child control, when CListCtrl is on focus? I tried like:

```
    ON_CONTROL_REFLECT(ID_EDIT_COPY, &CMyListCtrl::OnEditCopy)
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use same ON_COMMAND macro in CMyListCtrl.

```
  ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_COPY, &CMyListCtrl::OnEditCopy)
```

All you have to do is overriding OnCmdMsg method.

```
BOOL CMyFormView::OnCmdMsg(UINT nID, int nCode, void* pExtra, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO* pHandlerInfo)
{
    if (GetFocus() == m_myListCtrl
        && m_myListCtrl->OnCmdMsg(nID, nCode, pExtra, pHandlerInfo))
        return TRUE;
    return CMyFormView::OnCmdMsg(nID, nCode, pExtra, pHandlerInfo);
}
```

(m_myListCtrl is the CMyListCtrl instance pointer.)

This make all WM_COMMAND message first handled in m_myListCtrl if its the focus window.

Comment: Would you like to extend the answer by describing what role, if any, ::OnCommand() method plays in this case? Why ID_EDIT_COPY is so special that it needs the message dispatching mechanism to be modified in the parent class?

Answer (score 5):

Alternative you can override PreTranslateMessage() on CMyListCtrl and call TranslateAccelerator()

```
BOOL CMyListCtrl::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
       if (m_hAccelTable)
       {
          if (::TranslateAccelerator(m_hWnd, m_hAccelTable, pMsg))
             return(TRUE);
       }
       return CListCtrl::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

It requires acccess to the global accelerator-resource on the mainframe, or that you load the accelerator again. Then your CMyListCtrl will receive the WM_COMMAND messages specified in the accelerator table.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222829

Comment: Pity the support link is no longer valid.